# detect internet speed, running if function to load different index html files

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

I am using speedof.me api to detect the speed, based on the download result I need to load 3 or 4 different index files. This a beginner question, but I have been trying to read the object's "testResult.download" property for hours and run it on an if function, then do actions.

Comment: But what exactly is your question? How to access the object?

Comment: HI and welcome to Stack Overflow.
To help us to help you, can you post the code to show us what you have tried so far.